# PHP cURL, memory leak when using CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER

Tags: php, memory-leaks, curl

The following code is in a loop. Each loop changes $URI to a new address.
My problem is that each pass takes up more and more memory.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URI);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I finally worked out that if I comment out the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER line the leak stops.

I use "CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true" so I can get the result of the cURL operation as a string to parse. But, it would appear that the memory used to store this string is not parsed with each pass.
Can anyone suggest a way to clear this buffer and recover the used memory? Is there a destructor I could use, I've tried __destruct() but can't seem to get the syntax right.

Thanks
C

Comment: you are using php 5.2 or php 5.3?

Comment: in php5.3 you can call function gc_collect_cycles(); every amount of cycles in your loop

Comment: Thanks. V 5.1.6. Not sure why its so low I've only just inastalled it.

Comment: @Columbo: depends on your system. Windows? Linux? Which distribution when running Linux? If you installed it from a repository you will most likely get an older version of php. The best thing would be to copy the sources from php.net and compile it... ;-).

Comment: do you check content length for each url?

Comment: Sorry, yes. Linux CentOS. I did install form a repository, I will go and upgrade now.

Comment: I don't check content length no.

Comment: Have you tried reusing the curl object? You don't have to reinstantiate each iteration, just reset the URL and re-execute.

Comment: you should, what if one of the URL return lots of data?

Comment: Good point. I will start checking.

Comment: Well, I'm now on PHP 5.3 and it's not leaking anymore. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 5.1.6 of PHP seems to have an issue with memory leaking when using "CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true" to store the results of the cURL as a string.
Upgrading to 5.3 sorted the leak out for me.

Thanks

Comment: Too bad... I still have this issue with PHP Version 5.3.8 :-(

Comment: Hi, I am still suffering from this issue, did you get any solutions for it?? I am running PHP 5.3.21.