# PHP cUrl loop leaking memory

Tags: php, curl, memory-leaks, foreach

The following code is in a loop. Each loop changes URL to a new address. My problem is that each pass takes up more and more memory.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://site.ru/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 'http://site.ru/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$html = new \DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML(curl_exec($ch));

curl_close($ch);
$ch = null;

$xpath = new \DOMXPath($html);
$html = null;

foreach ($xpath->query('//*[@id="tree"]/li[position() > 5]') as $category) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xpath->query('./a', $category)->item(0)->nodeValue);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 'http://site.ru/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

    $html = new \DOMDocument();
    $html->loadHTML(curl_exec($ch));

    curl_close($ch);
    $ch = null;

    // etc.
}
```

The memory is 2000 Mb. Script execution time ~ 2h. PHP version 5.4.4.
How to avoid memory leak? Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use functions ? for good understanding and practice

Comment: I tried this with `ini_set('memory_limit' ,'2GB');` and got success in PHP **5.6.0**. What is your PHP version?

Comment: `5.3.*` seems to use large memory.

Answer (score 4):

Stories from the internet indicate that `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true)` is broken in for some PHP/cURL versions:

- [#13225   Memmory leak in curl](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=13225)
- [#40831   cURL extension doesnt clear buffer for reused handle](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40831)
- [PHP script memory leak issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836171/php-script-memory-leak-issue)
- [PHP cURL, memory leak when using CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498976/php-curl-memory-leak-when-using-curlopt-returntransfer)

You can also find stories for `DOM`:

- [DOMDocument PHP Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379829/domdocument-php-memory-leak)
- [PHP/DOMDocument: unset() does not release resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703164/php-domdocument-unset-does-not-release-resources?lq=1)
- [DOMDocument / Xpath leaking memory during long command line process - any way to deconstruct this class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188729/domdocument-xpath-leaking-memory-during-long-command-line-process-any-way-to?lq=1)

Create a minimal test case which spots the cause of the leak. I.e. remove the unrelated package (DOM or cURL) from the code.

Then reproduce it with the latest PHP version. If it's still causing the leak, [file a bug report](https://bugs.php.net/) else use that PHP version.

Answer (score 3):

Reuse the same curl handle instead of creating and destroying it each time in your loop.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 'http://site.ru/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
foreach ($pages as $url) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```